# C externs that alias the same address?

Tags: c, global-variables, standards-compliance

Can a C compiler assume that two different extern globals *cannot* be aliased to the same address?

In my case, I have a situation like this:

```
extern int array_of_int[], array_end;

void some_func(void)
{
    int *t;
    for (t = &array_of_int[0]; t != &array_end; t++)
    {
    ...
```

The resulting binary compiled with optimization on does not test the

```
t != &array_end
```

condition before entering the loop.  The compiler's optimization is that the loop must execute at least once since `t` cannot immediately equal `&array_end` at the outset.

Of course we found this the hard way.  Apparently, some assembler hackery with linker sections resulted in a case where the two externs are the same address.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Aha, only _now_ I get it. The code is trying to rely on the layout of data in the data segment of the object file containing array_of_int[]... That _is_ dirty. I posted the canonical version...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes, it's free to make that assumption.  There is nothing special about `extern` variables.  Two variables may not be aliases of each other.  (If the answer was any different, think about the chaos that would ensue.  `extern int a, b` could alias each other, which would make the semantics of any code using those variables completely insane!)

<s>In fact, you are relying on undefined behaviour here, full stop. It is not valid to compare addresses of unrelated variables in this way.</s>

Comment: Yes, it is undefined behaviour. It was quite subtle to spot, so [I posted a 'fixed' version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559281/c-externs-that-alias-the-same-address/5559351#5559351) that is quite likely to be what @srking intended

Comment: The inequality comparison isn't undefined, but falling off the end of the array (because `array_end` can't have the same address as any of its elements) is. This code would be legal and portable if something in the body of the loop ensures it always breaks before that happens.

Comment: @Steve: You are correct.  I have been misinterpreting the standard until now!

Comment: @Steve Jessop: It is legal for the pointer `t` to point one past the end of the array, and this address is allowed to compare equal to the address of an unrelated object.

Comment: @caf: agreed, what I meant was that there's no portable way to ensure that the address of `array_end` is equal to that one-off-the-end pointer -- presumably the code in question relied on non-portable details of globals layout. So the termination condition isn't portable, on another implementation it could go beyond one-off-the-end, and then you'd have UB simply from incrementing the pointer. My comment was in response to text about UB that Oli has since removed, look at the revision history if you're deeply interested in why I made it :-)

Comment: @Steve, @caf: Re-added the removed text in strike-out, for context.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 says in 6.2.2 "Linages of identifiers":

> An identifier declared in different
>   scopes or in the same scope more than
>   once can be made to refer to the same
>   object or function by a process called
>   linkage. (Footnote 21)
>
> ...
>
> Footnote 21: There is no linkage
>   between different identifiers.

So unfortunately, this somewhat common assembly language trick (that I've used...) isn't well-defined. You'd be better to have your assembly module define `array_end` to be be actual pointer that the asm code loads with the address of the end of the array.  That way the C code can be well-defined since the `array_end` pointer would be a separate object.

Comment: I'm not sure how interested the owners will be in fixing this code, but I can at least cause them some blunt force trauma with Footnote 21.  Cheers.

Comment: excellent explanation; always nice to see the chaps with the specs under their arm :)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple in case if we do it in arm code - 
we have an attribute for it ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int oldname = 1;
extern int newname __attribute__((alias("oldname"))); // declaration
void foo(void)
{
    printf("newname = %d\n", newname); // prints 1
}
```

and only extern is enough here. 
To import it in other files - its seamless.
for assembly file - you can use IMPORT command and you have alias there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think here's the fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int array_of_int[];
extern int *array_end;


int main()
{
    int *t;
    for (t = &array_of_int[0]; t != array_end; t++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", *t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in another compilation unit:

```
int array_of_int[] = { }; // { 1,2,3,4 };
int *array_end = array_of_int + (sizeof(array_of_int)/sizeof(array_of_int[0]));
```

It compiles into this (-O3, gcc 4.4.5 i686)

```
080483f0 <main>:
 80483f0:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483f1:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483f3:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483f6:       53                      push   %ebx
 80483f7:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 80483fa:       81 3d 24 a0 04 08 14    cmpl   $0x804a014,0x804a024
 8048401:       a0 04 08 
 8048404:       74 2f                   je     8048435 <main+0x45>
 8048406:       bb 14 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a014,%ebx
 804840b:       90                      nop
 804840c:       8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 8048410:       8b 03                   mov    (%ebx),%eax
 8048412:       83 c3 04                add    $0x4,%ebx
 8048415:       c7 44 24 04 00 85 04    movl   $0x8048500,0x4(%esp)
 804841c:       08 
 804841d:       c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
 8048424:       89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048428:       e8 d7 fe ff ff          call   8048304 <__printf_chk@plt>
 804842d:       39 1d 24 a0 04 08       cmp    %ebx,0x804a024
 8048433:       75 db                   jne    8048410 <main+0x20>
 8048435:       83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 8048438:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 804843a:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 804843b:       89 ec                   mov    %ebp,%esp
 804843d:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 804843e:       c3                      ret    
 804843f:       90                      nop
```

Comment: Right, but that's not what the OP is describing/asking about.

Comment: point taken, there was another strange thing happening there in the loop condition, I posted my fix to the code